# REACT: what would stop 'npm start' from working. localhost:3000 doesn't open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal

So, I installed the basic React file setup and when I use 'npm start' nothing happens, but if I switch to a different user on the same computer the exact same setup and command works just fine and localhost:3000 opens automatically.

So my question is, what could possibly be causing this and how do I fix it?

the code:
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

the result:
peterfaretra@Peters-MacBook-Pro React % npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 98 in 10.58s

Creating a new React app in /Users/peterfaretra/Sites/React/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

- react-scripts@3.4.3
- react-dom@16.13.1
- cra-template@1.0.3
- react@16.13.1
  added 1605 packages from 755 contributors and audited 1605 packages in 173.919s

69 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

- @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
- @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
- @testing-library/react@9.5.0
  added 36 packages from 57 contributors and audited 1641 packages in 12.107s

69 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

removed 1 package and audited 1640 packages in 6.202s

69 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Created git commit.

Success! Created my-app at /Users/peterfaretra/Sites/React/my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

npm start
Starts the development server.

npm run build
Bundles the app into static files for production.

npm test
Starts the test runner.

npm run eject
Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

cd my-app
npm start

Happy hacking!
peterfaretra@Peters-MacBook-Pro React %
peterfaretra@Peters-MacBook-Pro React % cd my-app
peterfaretra@Peters-MacBook-Pro my-app % npm start
peterfaretra@Peters-MacBook-Pro my-app %

Using Mac with most recent OS
Node is up to date
Terminal I reset, it wasn't that.
disabled virus software
I'm thinking about reinstalling the whole OS but I cant be bothered to go through the ordeal of putting it all back the way I want it.
very frustrating. please help.

Comment: Please try npm run start or share your package.json to see if you have added or modified any script

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `cd my-app npm start`  What is the result that you see after running npm start on this newly created app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm start does nothing / localhost:3000 connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907402/npm-start-does-nothing-localhost3000-connection-refused)

Comment: Oh, wow, that's the same exact repost by OP.  I like `connection refused`, at least the error message is in that post!

Comment: Ive added the package.json as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```